# Angular error when run this command "npm run dev:ssr" to watch the website how server side rendering is done in localhost

Tags: angular, npm, server-side-rendering

When run this command it start listening at port 4200 but it continuously loading the page but never load the page and show this error in cmd.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
} Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
```

File :- **server.ts**

Actually I am facing the problem that in ngAfterViewInit function I have a created the function of scroll down but in that function for particular element of HTML the id didn't fetch its because the component is still not loading and I think that there is an error in ssr but for running command to watch in ssr mode in localhost it will show the above error in cmd. So here I have given server.ts file as some one requested in the comment.

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import { join } from 'path';
const domino = require('domino');
import * as request from 'request';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as compress from 'compression';
import * as cookieparser from 'cookie-parser';
import 'zone.js/node';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import { environment } from './src/environments/environment';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { httpAuth } from './src/server/http-auth';
import { cacheResponse, cachedResponse } from './src/server/caching';

const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const indexPath = join(distFolder, 'index.html');
const indexHtml = existsSync(indexPath) ? 'index.html' : 'index';
const win = domino.createWindow(readFileSync(indexPath).toString());
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global.localStorage = localStorage;
global.window = win;
global.document = win.document;
global.branch = null;
global.object = win.object;
(global as any).navigator = win.navigator;

export async function app(): Promise<express.Express> {
  const server = express();

  server.use(compress(), cookieparser());

  if (environment.staging) {
    server.use(httpAuth);
  }

  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({ bootstrap: AppServerModule }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  server.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res) => {
    request(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/sitemap.xml`,
      { json: true },
      (err: Error, _res, body) => {
        if (err) return console.warn(err);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.end(body);
      }
    );
  });

  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, { maxAge: '1y' }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', cachedResponse, (req, res) => {
    res.render(
      indexHtml,
      {
        req,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
          { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
          { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
        ],
      },
      cacheResponse(req, res)
    );
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  app().then((server) => {
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  });
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: show your server.ts file

Comment: its your custom command in package.json ? can you post the file ?

Comment: No, not a custom command. This command is available in angular docs https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: You do not have to install Redis server. as an example see: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the redis server and then run the file redis-server.exe. Then run the command of SSR "npm run dev:ssr".